# Running ZeroBrane from Lua

Tags: debugging, lua, zerobrane

Given that ZeroBrane is all written in Lua, can it be actually started from within a Lua environment?

The main motivation would be to fully integrate it inside an existing application (running within the same thread), being able to debug locally using all the exposed C/C++ functionality.

I realize I would have to match the architecture of the clibs used by ZeroBrane with the one used in the host application.  So for example, if the host app is running LuaJIT 64-bit I would then require wx.dll compiled against the same LuaJIT binaries.

Will there be any other hurdles or limitations when trying to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Given that ZeroBrane is all written in Lua, can it be actually started from within a Lua environment?

The answer to this question is definitely "yes", as this is what ZeroBrane actually does. For example, on Windows it launches itself by loading `src/main.lua` and executing it; this code can be seen in [win32_starter.c](https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBraneStudio/blob/master/build/win32_starter.c#L53).

> Will there be any other hurdles or limitations when trying to do this?

I think the issue you're likely to run into is that it's difficult to debug a single-threaded application from itself (not impossible though). This is why normally the IDE (and its debugger) is launched as a separate process that interacts with the application that's being debugged over socket. You may want to check [debugger.lua](https://github.com/slembcke/debugger.lua), which may be closer to what you're looking for.